# Labview OPC UA component in LabView

Tags: labview, opc, opc-ua

I have never used LabView and I have to implement communication between OP UA server and OPC UA client. Please some one tell me how to add OPC server icon in labview it is not presnt in data communication. I just can not figure out where that OPC Icon is present in toolbar from where I can drag and drop the OPC component.

[image: Trying to find OPC]   [image: http://zone.ni.com/images/reference/en-XX/help/370622M-01/loc_bd_create_svr_support_non_secure_connection.gif]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should have **LabVIEW DSC 2013** installed.

Comment: I have installed the Real Time module. DO i need this one also?

Comment: I think yes, you should try

Comment: I have installed it but could not find it. Am I missing something else here

Comment: The Real Time module is not relevant here unless you're running your LabVIEW code under a real-time OS - e.g. on a cRIO system. Looking at http://sine.ni.com/nips/cds/view/p/lang/en/nid/209059 the OPC server may be a separate module from the DSC toolkit? I would suggest asking at the NI website.

Comment: I just found it. It was in data communication.It worked by installing DSC

Comment: By the way, if you press Ctrl-Space in the LabVIEW development environment you should bring up the Quick Drop window in which you can search for a VI in the palettes by name.

Comment: It was not there first I search using it. But by installing DSC i got it by searching. Thanks and yes Real time seems useless.cheers